# How to show elements based on user role?

Tags: jsp

I'm fairly new to JSP so I have no clue on where to even start. I made a webapp, but I need to split it into an admin and user without actually making two different jsps for each of them.

I have a seperate API for the login and user list so most of the tutorials I checked wont work here. (I used ajax to get the info from my db)

I saw a post in that suggest something like the one below, but I'm not sure how that works

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <c:if test="${role.admin == true}">
        only admin could see this content
    </c:if>
    
     <c:if test="${role.supervisor == true}">
     <a href="">only supervisor's link</a>
     </c:if>
    
      every one can see this content
```

Would really appreciate it if anyone can help out with this

Comment: that code simply check if `role.admin` value has `true` then show content which is under that statement and so on .? what you didn't understood here?

Comment: @Swati if im not mistaken, here `role` is an object. I'm not sure where it was made. I do my login verification by calling a different API using AJAX and using js to validate it

Comment: You can store users roles i.e : `admin,supervisior..etc` somewhere in [session](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) and then access same in your jsp page  .Also what do you mean by different API here its in java only or some other language? Also, without seeing more code  i cannot suggest you anything more then this .

Comment: i mean, the API (Spring boot rest) is a separate project, so I cant directly call the java objects in it. I access it using their url